# Overwirte a paragraph in p tag which has an image element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is an image in a p tag, I want to overwrite the paragraph in the p tag but keep the image, how to do that?

I tried InnerText, but it will overwrite the image.

Any other method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+change+innerText+without+site%3Dstackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: i'd go grabbing the img attributes, replace the p text and in the text also insert a new img tag with the same attributes